# Refresh only GridView on Parent page after pop-up window close

Tags: gridview, updatepanel, refresh

I have a gridview inside updated panel on parent page which is populated based on some search criteria (in text-boxes and dropdownlists). It has a request status field along with some other fields. There is a button which opens a popup window (Aspx page) where user can select approver and submit request. I'd like to auto refresh gridview (also retaining the search criteria) on parent page with current request status once pop-up window is closed.

I'm using modalWin to open a pop-up page.

### Update

I still am looking for an answer. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following steps to acheive the same:

**Popup Page:**

1. Add call back and Event name of the parent page

asp:button id="submitButton" runat="server" text="Submit" OnClientClick="window.opener.__doPostBack('Search_OnClick','');">

**Parent page CodeBehind:**

1. Add the code in Parent

   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   { 
       this.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, string.Empty);

   ```
   if (this.IsPostBack)
       {
           string eventTarget = (this.Request["__EVENTTARGET"] == null) ? string.Empty : this.Request["__EVENTTARGET"];

           if (eventTarget == "btnSearch_Click")
           {
             btnSearch_Click(sender, e);
           }
       }
   ```

   }

Comment: it should be like this,
if (eventTarget == "Search_OnClick")
                {
                    btnSearch_Click(sender, e);
                }